# Any generic layout analysis library or tool not based on OCR?

Tags: pdf, image-processing

I am looking for layout analysis libraries or tools (preferably open source) that can be applied on text PDFs to identify main text content versus sidebars, chapter headings, section headings (possibly even fancy ones having decorations/shading and underlines) etc. I came across tools like OCRopus which use OCR and image recognition to identify the layout. Are there libraries which can do the same WITHOUT OCR? It is possible to extract text and images from text PDFs and give an input that contains positions of text and images to the tool; using OCR for such files would be rather circuitous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am not aware of such stand-alone (as in not dependent on OCR or image processing) libraries but you should be able to use the layout detection piece of OCRopus or OCRFeeder (https://live.gnome.org/OCRFeeder). Have you looked at the latter? Apparently, it is designed to work with almost any standard OCR engine, meaning the layout analysis part alone can be used by creating your own "virtual OCR" that extracts data based on your custom logic (rather than any real image processing) and passing that to OCRFeeder.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally I too happened to come across OCRFeeder after posting this question, though I am yet to try using it.